# Make tkinter window draw on top of fullscreen applications

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm wondering if there is a way to draw tkinter windows over fullscreen applications, so far I have this:

```
from tkinter import *

#MAIN WINDOW
root = Tk()
root.title('Test Title')
root.geometry("500x200")
root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', root['bg'])
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)


my_frame = Frame(root, width=500, height=200)
my_frame.pack(pady=20, ipady=20, ipadx=20)

#STAT TEXT
my_label = Label(my_frame, font=("Helvetica", 40), fg="#09d2f6")
my_label.config(text="TEST TEXT")
my_label.pack(pady=20)


root.mainloop()
```

This draws the window on top of all applications but not fullscreen ones. I had the idea to have a loop where it will constantly bring the window forward but have no idea how to do that.

Comment: You might be able to use the tkinter [`after()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) widget method to repeatedly schedule a call to a function that executed a `root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)`

Comment: The problem is with the fullscreen window you mention, it must be set to `-topmost', not just `fullscreen`. I'll post an example of a fullscreen background and your code running together - without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will enable you to choose a picture to view on the fullscreen.

Your code will run in transparent mode above it - no problems

Press Escape key to exit

Try making your widget fullscreen using title button for weird effect!

Had to edit this due to the effect of `filedialog` on results.

Moved the attribute setting so that it is invoked after image is loaded.

```py
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def closer( ev ):
    ev.widget.destroy()

# FULL SCREEN
master = tk.Tk()
master.rowconfigure( 0, weight = 1 )
master.columnconfigure( 0, weight = 1 )

master.bind( "<Escape>", closer )

pathfile = filedialog.askopenfilename( title = 'pick mage' )

my_image = tk.PhotoImage( file = pathfile ).zoom( 2,2 )
label = tk.Label( master, text = 'Image', compound = "top", image = my_image )
label.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky='nsew')

master.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", 1)
# removed for first time use - unrem this for second time
# master.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)

# Your code

root = tk.Toplevel(master)
root.title('Test Title')
root.geometry("500x200")

root.bind( "<Escape>", closer )

root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', root['bg'])
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)

my_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=500, height=200)
my_frame.pack(pady=20, ipady=20, ipadx=20)

#STAT TEXT
my_label = tk.Label(my_frame, font=("Helvetica", 40), fg="#09d2f6")
my_label.config(text="TEST TEXT")
my_label.pack(pady=20)

master.mainloop()
```