# Tkinter force window on top of any windows even in fullscreen

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

i have the code below:

```py
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Controller, Button
from pynput import keyboard
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk
import os
side = 0
mouse = Controller()
keycon = Controller()
window = tk.Tk()
logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="dirt.png")

window.overrideredirect(1)
window.overrideredirect(0)
window.attributes('-alpha',0.8)
window.attributes("-topmost", True)
window.lift()
window.update()
window.geometry("110x40+1560+0")
wayclick = tk.Label(compound = tk.CENTER, text="Side: None", font=("Verdana 15 bold"), image=logo, fg="white")
wayclick.pack()
def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    if side == 0:
        mouse.press(Button.left)
        mouse.release(Button.left)
        sleep(0.01)
    elif side == 1:
        mouse.press(Button.right)
        mouse.release(Button.right)
        sleep(0.01)
def on_press(key):
    try:
        if(key == key.caps_lock):
            global side
            global wayclick
            if side == 0: 
                side = 1
                wayclick.config(text = "Side: RIGHT")
            else: 
                side = 0
                wayclick.config(text = "Side: LEFT")
    except AttributeError:
        pass
# ...or, in a non-blocking fashion
print("Scroll clicking by ELEMENT")
print("Close the Terminal to stop or Ctrl + Z")
while True:
    sidea = input("left/right> ")
    if sidea == "left" or sidea == "right": break
    else: print("Incorrect options")
if sidea == "left": 
    side = 0
    wayclick.config(text = "Side: LEFT")
else: 
    side = 1
    wayclick.config(text = "Side: RIGHT")
with Listener(on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listenerkb:
            window.mainloop()
            listenerkb.join()
            listener.join()
```

I want the window to stay on top of any windows even if the window is in fullscreen

The result I want:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXbOc.png)

But how can I do it? I tried window.attributes("-topmost", True) and
window.lift(), but it is only on top of the other windows if the window is not fullscreen. Please help me!

Comment: The window you want to stay on top should be `tk.Toplevel` and made `transient`

Comment: Also here is a link that may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68552627/make-tkinter-window-draw-on-top-of-fullscreen-applications